Is it possible to define tab-local mappings?
I am wondering if it is possible to define mappings that are tab local, something like nnoremap <tab> h :echo "hello".

There's no such thing. You could emulate something like this with the TabEnter and TabLeave autocommands. It's unclear what you're trying to achieve. If you [edit] and clarify, maybe somebody will find another way to get there.

What’s unclear?

Surely, you don't intend to :echo "hello". I could imagine you want to have one tab for writing code and one for debugging but that's just my interpretation. If you tell us what you want to accomplish in the big picture, somebody may hint to a solution without tab-local mappings. If taken at face value, the answer to your question is "no".

I want mappings that applies only to a specific tab. Nothing more, nothing less. It's not an XY question. That feature can serve multiple purposes, not only for writing code/debugging. The :echo "hello" is an example. I am fine with "no" as an answer.

Thank you for clarifying. I hope somebody will prove me wrong and write an actual answer.

Not really, but to an extent/functionally you can emulate it with map-expr.
For example:
nnoremap <expr> <tab> tabpagenr() == 1 ? '<tab>' : ':echo "hello from tab ' . tabpagenr() . '"<CR>'

Would keep the normal functionality (go up in jump list) in the first tab, and echo the tab number in other tabs.

If tabs have IDs, using them  will be more robust to layout changes
